# AJAX Posting with Relative URL in MVC 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC 5 web application that I am using AJAX Posts to call Controller Actions with. Let's say I have a controller named "Account" and an action on that controller named "Create".

To call that action, I have been using code similar to this, called from my Account/Index view, served from accessing an Account/Index GET action.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Create",
        data: dataVar,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,

        datatype: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#result').html(data);
        }
    });
```

This isn't my exact code, but it show's my purpose. I've been using "/Create" as the POST url. This has been working fine with no problem, until seemingly randomly today it stopped being able to find the action method. I fixed this by using @Url.Action to generate the correct URL to post to, which is fine, but I want to know if I really need to. (Pseudo-code below)

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("Create","Account")",
        data: dataVar,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,

        datatype: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#result').html(data);
        }
    });
```

Is there something wrong with the way I had it before, where the post url was relative to the current controller? Should I avoid this, and always use a function to generate my url?

I'm especially curious why "/Create" was working before, but suddenly must be called as "/Account/Create" now. Any ideas there? A setting in web.config or something?

Comment: Are you really sure that `"/Create"` was working? It actually should have been `"/Account/Create"` all the time.

Comment: Yes, I am 100% positive it was working. I confirmed the code executed in Visual Studio using the debugger, as well as double checked the effects in the database. I intend to change everything to use the Url.Action function anyways, but was curious as to what could have happened (to break it, or to allow it to begin with when it shouldn't have)

Comment: Are you working LOCALLY , Broswer cache your content. Test it with after reload page pressing. CRTL +F5

Comment: I tested locally and on 2 different application pools on a webserver running IIS 6. Before, the short URL worked on all 3, and now, it doesn't work on any 3. That also included clearing the cache and it still worked after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further research, it seems that when my code was executed using the shortened URL, it was just a fluke. The correct way to enter the url for the AJAX call is by using the full relative path or the Razor helper function, like here:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "@Url.Action("Create","Account")",
    data: dataVar,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,

    datatype: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        $('#result').html(data);
    }
});
```

If using the Url.Action method and your javascript is not on your view page, the url must be passed through the view page to your javascript.